# Excess elements in array initializer C++ char Xcode

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, char, osx-yosemite

My first name has six letters and my second name has four.

The incorrect code will build and print:

```
char myName[4][6] = {{'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'}, {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'}};
```

But the correct code will not:

```
char myName [6] [4] = {{'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'}, {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'}};
```

Is there a reason that:

- the second array `[4]` is being applied to the first set of characters?
- the first array `[6]` is being applied to the second set of characters?

I am using the most recent version of Xcode. Is there some sort of glitch where arrays are inverted or something? I've looked around but I can't find anything explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a `char myName[4][6]` is a four element array of six `char` arrays (so your data will fit).  where as `char myName[6][4]` is six arrays of four `char` arrays (which will not fit your six `char` array).

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense... On the tutorial I watched - he was entering two five letter names and typed it like this:

char myName [5][5] = etc...

Threw me off.

Comment: While that answer is correct, you could expand it a bit to show what the poster really wants. The poster seems to be under the impression that myName[6][4] is declaring a two element array with the first element being a 6 element array and the second a 4 element array, which isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[0] [0][1] [0][2]
```

```
char[1] [1][1] [1][2]
```

And also, you can put an array into an array. So if you imagine this, you can have pages of arrays. Just link do something like..

```
int a[0] = b[4];
```

That will put b[4][...] into the single cell of a[0]. Useful for games or whatnot.

Comment: So with both arrays and characters you begin counting at 0? (0, 1, 2, etc.) That is to say, char [2] [4] is actually 3 arrays of 5 characters?

Comment: And btw, the access to that b[4] is a[0[0]], i believe